# Does the brain burn more calories when "thinking quickly"?

Tags: brain-development

If a person intentionally "thinks quickly" would this affect how much glucose the brain consumes? Or would it not be very significant?

Comment: This has a duplicate on biology.stackexchange.com
https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/839/how-does-the-brains-energy-consumption-depend-on-mental-activity/851#851

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a duplicate of a Biology question that has already been answered.

Comment: @Christianhummeluhr -  Is that a reason to close it across sites?

Comment: @AliceD Well, obviously I think so, since I voted to close for that reason. We could copy their answer over, I suppose.